# Aura iteration is not holding on particular selection value resetting to first value every time loop is started

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute, aura-if

```
<lightning:select label="Permissionset Names" onchange="{!c.doInit}" >
     <option>None</option>
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.set}" var ="d">  
         <option>{!d.Name}</option> 
     </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

controller:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  //call apex class method
  var action = component.get('c.PermissionSetLst');
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
   //store state of response
   var state = response.getState();

   if (state === "SUCCESS") {

    //set response value in ListOfAccount attribute on component.
    component.set('v.set', response.getReturnValue());
   }
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
```

this works fine for me it give me a required result but it is not holding on its value it get reset to first value i want it on selection the value will be displayed like my lightning select.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use [lightning:combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/example) instead of `lightning:select`.

You just need to set `selected` in options OR set `value` attribute on `combobox` to set a selection:

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
{'label': 'New', 'value': 'new'},
{'label': 'In Progress', 'value': 'inProgress'},
{'label': 'Finished', 'value': 'finished'},
]"/>

<lightning:combobox name="progress" label="Status" 
                    value="inProgress" 
                    placeholder="Select Progress" 
                    options="{! v.options }" 
                    onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
```

it chooses `value="inProgress"` by default and if you remove `value="inProgress"`, nothing will be selected

---

If you have to use `lightning:select` only, you can set selected on options:

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
{'label': 'New', 'value': 'new'},
{'label': 'In Progress', 'value': 'inProgress'},
{'label': 'Finished', 'value': 'finished', 'selected':true},
]"/>

<lightning:select label="Permissionset Names" >
    <option>None</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var ="d">  
        <option selected="{!d.selected}" value='{!d.value}'>{!d.label}</option> 
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

**You should also use `value` on options to get the selected value onchange**

Comment: how to call my function which i made here  i want to iterate around my function values.

Comment: sorry got the solution two actions work for me thanks all for kind help your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set selected value for `lightning:select`. This can be done in below two ways:

**Using html attribute**

```
<option value="{!d.Name}" selected="{!d.Name==v.selectedValue}">{!d.Name}</option>.
```

Here `v.selectedValue` is selected value may be from record or selected by you in last action.

**using JS controller:**

```
<lightning:select label="Permissionset Names" onchange="{!c.doInit}" aura:id="permList" >
     <option>None</option>
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.set}" var ="d">  
         <option>{!d.Name}</option> 
     </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

JS controller:

```
component.find("permList").set("v.value", 'selected value'); //your selected value is last selected value.
```

Comment: still after using html attribute it is bydefault setting to first value loop iterates.

Comment: Please add your code with above solution.

Comment: theiir is a problem with my controller i fixed that issue is fixed.